# NSString length and retainCount. Clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Based on the following code, please advise

```
NSString *str= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"];   

NSLog(@"Length: %lu\n", [str length]);              // 11
NSLog(@"Retain count is %lu\n", [str retainCount]); //1152921504606846975

[str release];

NSLog(@"%lu\n", [str length]);                      // 11
NSLog(@"Retain count is %lu\n", [str retainCount]); //1152921504606846975
```

1. Originally I was wondering why the number was so large but then saw a a [post explaining it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390334/nsstring-retain-count). Let me ask this instead ... Why does this number change greatly whether i use `%d` vs `%lu`. Originally, i used `%d`, but got a warning saying that "*Conversion specified type int but the argument has the type NSUInteger (aka unsigned long). A fix was to change `%d` to `%lu`"*
2. Why doesn't the retain count decrement? Large number still shows up unchanged, after the `str` is sent `release`
3. Why am i still able to access the `str`, after it was sent `release`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be a hard answer to accept, but it's what you should do:

1. **Don't worry about it.** (in terms of %d/%lu, those specifiers simply expect different data types, and %d (int) has a much smaller and different range from %lu (unsigned long))
2. **Don't worry about it.**
3. **Don't do it, and especially don't rely on it.**

It may be because you started with a constant string (`@"Hello world"`) that the memory isn't being deallocated when you call release, and the retainCount is large. But *if you have to care about the retainCount, you're doing it wrong.*

You are releasing the string in the right place, and that's what matters — don't ever try to use it later.

Comment: everything I've read about retain counts in objective-c leads me to the same conclusion.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Soon we'll have ARC, and then we'll see what the next level of difficulty is.

Comment: The next level of difficulty will be mentally grasping object graphs :)

Comment: @jtbandes - In that case there will be a lot of questions asking about how to fix all the compiler errors Xcode and LLVM will throw up.

Comment: @Abizern: yeah, like "why can't I call `-release`??!1!"

Answer (score 0):

ultimately, the behaviour is defined by the implementation of NSString -- just use retain/release properly in every case and you will be safe.

what's likely happening: NSString literals are immortal. you can write `while (1) { [@"String" release]; }` and there will be no issue.

the copy ctor you have called is likely returning a pointer to the string literal. in pseudocode:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        if ([str _isStringLiteral] || [str _isImmutable]) {
            [self release];
            return [str retain];
        }
        ...
}
```

in this case, you are returned the pointer to the string literal, when passed through `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:stringLiteral]`. since sending `release` to the immortal string literal does nothing, you can see why it is still a valid object following what you could presume is a released object.

never rely on such details/optimizations, just use normal lifetimes and ref counting and you'll be fine.