# About the formation in NSLog in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
const char *string ="Hi there,this is a C string";
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithBytes:string 
                            length:strlen(string)+1];
NSLog(@"data is %@",data);
NSLog(@"%lu byte string is '%s'",[data length],[data bytes]);
```

This can be implied successfully. If the last sentence is:

```
NSLog(@"%d byte string is '%s'",[data length],[data bytes]);
```

it will warn that conversion specifies type 'int' but argument has typed 'NSUInteger' (aka'usigned long')

Why `%d` can't?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6727693/944634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUInteger is basically an unsigned long, so use %lu instead.

Comment: but the question is y the '%d' can't .The textbook wrote it.

Comment: I don't know what textbook you're reading, but in ObjC you need to pass the correct "long/short" and "signed/unsigned" in the format specifier. %lu is correct (long unsigned). %d (short, signed) is not.

Comment: thank you for you answer. Perhaps the textbook has to be improved or the translators.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

%d means 'int'. NSUInteger is not an 'int', so %d won't work. You have to match format specifiers with the type. If you specify the wrong type, your program can crash or more likely, it'll print garbage.

Comment: %d is for ints. %f for doubles. All the specifiers are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html