# Strange retain count of newly created string object

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"This is string object"];
    NSLog(@"%lu", [str retainCount]);
    [pool drain];


    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 1 becase it is newly created object, but the result is 1152921504606846.
What is wrong here ?

Comment: Don't use retainCount. See - [When to use -retainCount?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString retain Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390334/nsstring-retain-count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three important points:

1. This has nothing to do with autorelease pools. Your variable is `alloc`d, so it not added to the pool
2. Never use `retainCount` for debugging. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)
3. Your string is effectively a constant, so the retain count is *probably* MAX_INT. But you shouldn't rely on that

Comment: I agree with you, but why most of the books about objective-c use retainCount method for explanation of memory managment ?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to ask the authors.

Comment: It'll be `NSUIntegerMax`, not `INT_MAX` -- retain count is unsigned and in terms of Apple's typedef.

Answer (score 1):

See what beryllium said above ;)  Never use `-retainCount`  That said, there are two issues here:

The first isn't in the autorelease pool, but in your NSLog.

`-[NSObject retainCount]` returns an NSUInteger, which is either 32-bits wide or 64-bits wide, depending on the system architecture.  It's considered best practice to always cast NSInteger values to (long) and NSUInteger values to (unsigned long) when a function takes a variable number of arguments.  Hence:

```
NSLog(@"%l", (long)[str integerValue]
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str retainCount])
```

The second is an optimization: @"This is string object" is actually an NSString by itself, but a special NSString called a NSCFConstantString, which has a retain count of NSIntegerMax (meaning that they cannot be dealloc'd).

I just ran your original example, and it looks like an NSString initialized via `-initWithString:` returns the original string.  In this case, that's the constant string, so it's returning NSIntegerMax.

Answer (score -2):

Just change %lu to %d

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"This is string object"];
    NSLog(@"%d", [str retainCount]);
    [pool drain];


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `retainCount` returns an `NSUInteger`, so the `%lu` is the correct specifier. 2) You should never evaluate `retainCount`. 3) Because in this case, `NSString` will simply optimize itself away and return the *constant* (unreleaseable) string `@"This is string object"` instead of a new object which thus returns a very high number for `retainCount`.