# Why retain count in negative value?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, retaincount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString retain Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390334/nsstring-retain-count)

Is it possible that any object has its **retain count** in negative value ?

I have this code

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
NSLog(@"String Retain Count: %i", [str retainCount]);
```

this will return the **retain count** -1.

Why this happened ?

also I have done like this

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init]
```

still its return negative value in **retain count**.

How this is happening ?

Please help to understand this thing!!!!!

Comment: RetainCount is pretty much useless, as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: @kuba this is not a duplicate of that question so Please read what is my question.

Comment: @Rizzu: It *is a duplicate*. The returned retain count is `2147483647 ` and you got the output `-1` only because you printed the value with the `%i` format for signed integers.

Comment: Ok then what about "NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init]
" ?

Comment: @Rizzu: `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns a constant empty string. - The retain count is a `NSUInteger` so it *cannot be negative*.

Comment: @Rizzu It's just that you invoke UB by printing an unsigned integer using `%i` instead of `%llu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`retainCount` doesn't return the reference count of an object.](http://whentouseretaincount.com) - it returns unrelated nonsense.

(For performance reasons, immutable constant strings, when copied, return `self`. If you compare the pointer to `@""` and `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]`, they will be equal.)

Comment: Just a note: `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]` returns the same pointer as `@""`, but `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns a different (unique) pointer.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, updated. (How suboptimal Apple's code is! :P)