# NSString retainCount is 2147483647

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [NSString retain Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390334/nsstring-retain-count)
>   [Objective C NSString* property retain count oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403112/objective-c-nsstring-property-retain-count-oddity)
>   [When to use -retainCount ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Why does this code show the retain value greater than 1? And why is it 2147483647?

```
NSString *data22 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"fsdfsfsdf"];

int a = [data22 retainCount];
NSLog(@"retain count 1== %d  ====" ,a);
```

The output of the above code is

```
 retain count 1== 2147483647  ====
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It is 2147483647 because you looked.  Don't look and it will be the value you expect.

Seriously. Don't call `retainCount`.  Not ever.  It is useless.

*Why* it is such a ridiculous number is because of an implementation detail.  @"..." is a constant string.  `NSString` can recognize constant strings and decides that your particular code has no need of a second space consuming copy of a constant immutable string and, thus, returns the already existing constant string.

I.e. a singleton.  Of a class whose instances are only ever created by the compiler.  For which retain/release/autorelease/**retainCount** are utterly devoid of meaning.

As for why it is 2147483647, a picture is worth a thousand words. Or, in this case, 31 set bits.
[image: negative one expressed in far too many digits]

Comment: sorry i think i need a brief discussion of the pic

Comment: It was a bit of geek snark, admittedly.   But... glad you got it!