# Objective C - Crash due to double release?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

The following code should crash under "Manual reference count" since the objects inside the array are getting released twice. Why does it not crash?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:@"1"];
[array addObject:@"2"];
[array addObject:@"3"];


for (int i=array.count-1 ; i>= 0 ; i--)
{
    id object = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    [object release];
    [array removeObject:object];
}
```

Comment: Only call `release` if you own the object (called `alloc`, `retain`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`). You don't own the objects in the array so you must not release them.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that, my question wasn't why it crashes. It was why it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it not crash?

Because the objects in question are [object literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), which are treated somewhat differently. Basically, such objects are never deallocated. See [Objective C NSString* property retain count oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403112/643383) for a full explanation.

If you change the second line like this:

```
[array addObject:[stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
```

you should see the crash that you're expecting because the first item in the array will be not be a string constant, but rather a regular old dynamically allocated string subject to the usual reference counting rules.

Comment: For additional details, see the NSString section of https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html

Comment: Same result with NSDictionary being added to array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069459/does-some-text-give-an-autoreleased-or-retain-1-object-back

Comment: @aryaxt Was it a dictionary of the form `@{@"foo" : @"bar"}`? In other words, was it an [object literal](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)? I changed the wording in my answer to cover all object literals, not just strings.

Comment: No NSSidctionary dictionaryWithKeyAndValues:, finally got it to crash I'm happy now. Your solution wouldn't crash when I initialized all objects with 1, when I changed the numbers it crashes. Very weird.

Comment: Note that it's not impossible for `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]` to be optimized to a single constant string object. If you want to guarantee a unique object for tests  you should create a new mutable object like NSMutableString or NSMutableArray.